# The address is written on the back of the namecard

Tags: tense

> The address ***is*** written on the back of the namecard.
>
> The address ***was*** written on the back of the namecard.

Do we use simple tense or past tense in sentences above?

Comment: Well, that all depends on whether you intend to express a past condition or a present condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct. Whether you should use the present simple or the past simple depends upon the tense of the condition you want to refer to. If you want to refer to the matter in the present time, use the present simple. However, if you want to refer to the matter in the past, use the past simple.